# About infinite dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $W1$ and $W_2$ are two infinite dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$ over field $F$, prove or disprove that $W_1 \cap W_2 =0$ or $W_1 \cap W_2$ is infinite dimensional.

I have no clue in this question, can somebody give me some hints.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $V=L^2[0,\pi]$, $W_1$ is the span of $\{ \sin(x) \} \cup \{ \cos(nx) \}_{n=1}^\infty$, $W_2$ is the span of $\{ \sin(nx) \}_{n=1}^\infty$. What is the dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2$?

This idea works in general, just pick two disjoint infinite dimensional subspaces, then throw in an element from one into the other and close the result under linear combinations.